# When instantiating multiple GameObjects of one Prefab only the buttons of the last one created work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Me again with the same question. I spent couple of hours trying now and I could not find a solution for this problem. I will try to give as much information as possible.

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("List of items sold")]
    [SerializeField] private ShopItem[] shopItems;

    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform shopContainer;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject shopItemPrefab;
    List<GameObject> itemList = new List<GameObject>();
    public void Start()
    {
        PopulateShop();
    }

    private void PopulateShop()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < shopItems.Length; i++)
        {
            ShopItem si = shopItems[i];

            GameObject item = Instantiate(shopItemPrefab, shopContainer) as GameObject;


            //grab buttons to make listeners on them
                //buy button 

            item.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true).FirstOrDefault(t => t.name == "buyButton").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => buyButtonClick(si));
            //info button
            item.transform.Find("infoButton").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => infoButtonClick(item));
            //infoReturnButton
            item.transform.GetChild(5).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => infoCancelButtonClick(item));



            //change prefabs values
            item.transform.name = si.name;
            item.transform.GetChild(4).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = si.sprite;
            item.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<Text>().text = si.price.ToString();
            item.transform.GetChild(5).GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = si.infoText;

            itemList.Add(item);
        }


    }
    public void infoButtonClick(GameObject item)
    {
        GameObject currentInfo =item.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true).FirstOrDefault(t => t.name == "infoBackgroundImg").gameObject;
        currentInfo.SetActive(true);

    }

    public void buyButtonClick(ShopItem item)
    {
        Debug.Log("aki ist gay");
    }

    public void infoCancelButtonClick(GameObject item) 
    {
        GameObject currentInfo = item.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true).FirstOrDefault(t => t.name == "infoBackgroundImg").gameObject;
        currentInfo.SetActive(false);

    }

}
```

I am creating objects of one Prefab. The Prefabs structure is the following:

[image]

And I have a ShopItem which gives some values inserted into the Prefab looking like this:

[image]

Right now there are a total of 3 objects being created and all of this works just fine. the Problem is now that only the buttons of the last created object work. Let me show you my event system:

[image]:

This is Object3(the last one). As you can see the pointerpress works (buyButton). If we now go to f.e. object2 you can see that it does not even recognize that the button is there.

[image]

But when looking at the objects you can see that the button is there.

[image]

So I do not understand why the button only works for Obj 3 when Obj 1&2 also have the button and when I delete Obj 3 the buttons of Obj 2 start working.

I have no clue any more why it is not working.

Comment: "Me again with the same question" - have you asked this before? If so, readers will want to know why you are duplicating questions.

Comment: This is your prior question, and it does look like it is trying to solve the same problem: [Unity, creating multiple objects of one prefab leads to the buttons of only the last one working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873306/unity-creating-multiple-objects-of-one-prefab-leads-to-the-buttons-of-only-the)

Comment: yes it is, but i wanted to add more information and don´t know how to edit

Comment: Underneath the tags in your question is a link labelled `edit`

Comment: I don't have direct experience of Unity, but does the infoButton handler work? I notice the way you find the component in order to assign the handler for the two buttons (buyButton and infoButton) is different. Why?

Comment: It´s because I tried to do it in multiple different ways to see if it works. They all work with the last object but I can´t seem to get every button on every object to work

Comment: i suppose buttons or something is overlapping buttons, so you just access to the last button created

Answer (score 0):

Okay I see the problem and the solution will hopefully make your life much easier.

It's pretty tough to understand your code and it seems like you might be misunderstanding some functions that are causing you to make things more difficult for yourself than necessary, leading to this problem.

First:
    GameObject item = Instantiate(shopItemPrefab, shopContainer) as GameObject;
If you're instantiating a prefab (i.e. the prefab is the first argument) or any `GameObject`, `Instantiate()` returns a `GameObject` so there's no need to cast it. This is also part of the problem due to the next part:

```
        //grab buttons to make listeners on them
            //buy button
        item.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true).FirstOrDefault(t => t.name == "buyButton").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => buyButtonClick(si));
        //info button
        item.transform.Find("infoButton").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => infoButtonClick(item));
```

Here, you're adding all the functions to listen to a button. You have comments saying exactly what you expect to find, and you're searching for them by name. And yet... you're doing this all in a loop, and they all add to to the loop variable `item`.

Your code works fine. It's adding all three listeners to all three buttons (if it can).

If you're writing a loop and you have a bunch of different hardcoded cases, you might not actually need a loop. It should be something like

```
foreach(prefab in menu) 
    { //initialize prefab.button}
```

Another code smell that stands out:

```
        //infoReturnButton
        item.transform.GetChild(5).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => infoCancelButtonClick(item));
```

The multiple `GetChild` calls indicate that you know exactly what you're looking for and where you're looking for it. There's no reason to do this in a script then, that's the entire reason you're using Unity, so you can use the inspector to set these things up. If your buttons aren't being dynamically generated at runtime, then you don't need any of this whole script. And if they are, it's going to continue not working.

Your Canvas should have a parent item called `Info Menu` or something and that way you can simply enable and disable that in the inspector or at runtime if you need to hide the buttons, and you can even drop the whole thing premade into a new scene.

Additionally, your `GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener` is adding a listener to a `Button` component's `UnityEvent` list that exists entirely to enable you to assign events in the inspector. If you're trying to subscribe listeners at runtime, you should just have a regular C# `event` and have the components subscribe and unsubscribe in their `OnEnable()` and `OnDisable()` callbacks. Otherwise, you should be setting up those callbacks in the prefabs in the inspector.

As someone who has often spent hours trying to understand bugs I created by making my own life overcomplicated, I hope this helps!